# ASP.NET MVC 5 : model not binding to HttpPostedFileBase from Razor form w/jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I've read the many possible causes and solutions for this problem, but I don't see that any of them can help me.

I'm making a change to an already-existing project that uses jQuery-2.2.4 and jQuery-mobile-1.4.5

Somehow, the jQuery-mobile is interfering with the `<input type='file' ...` element from binding to the model. Commenting out the following line of code in my View's _Layout allows successful model binding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js")"></script>
```

This also breaks the layout of the existing UI. Converting the project to Bootstrap et al is not do-able any time soon.

Updated jQuery to 3.6.1, but this breaks jQuery-mobile 1.4.5 which is locked to jQuery 2.n.n

Updated to jQuery-mobile-1.5.0rc. It seems compatible with jQuery-3.6.1, but none of this fixed the model-binding issue for the HttpPostedFileBase ...

Somehow jquery-mobile is preventing MVC from binding the posted data. I can also see by way of Fiddler that the element is getting posted as NULL.

In the MVC Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Certification Photo")]
public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedPhoto { get; set; }
```

In the Razor View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Sitter.Certifications[i].UploadedPhoto,
    new {
        type = "file",
        data_certindex = i,
        accept = "image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp",
        style = "visibility: hidden; position:absolute;",
        @class = "form-control"
    }
)
```

When I select a file, I can see that the `value=` attribute of `UploadedPhoto` gets populated as expected, but when the form is posted Fiddler shows that UploadedPhoto is submitted empty and seen as NULL in the controller.

When I remove the jquery-mobile script, everything works perfectly.

I'm stuck with using jQuery-mobile for the time being. Does anyone know what causes this, and/or how to work around the issue?

UPDATE: Is there a way to disable jquery-UI events on a single control or the entire form? I've tried `data-role=none` but that doesn't seem to disable jQuery-UI events completely.

Comment: have you tried data-ajax=false on the form?